# Using javascript to read URL and direct to index

Tags: javascript, url, curl

I was not sure how to phrase the title so that'll have to do. I'm quite new to javascript and jquery.

What I have been wondering for a while is how I could - *using javascript or JQuery (prefer JQuery)* - read the URL that the user is currently on, and sort of manipulate it. Since I'm really not that great at explaining, I'll give an example:

**John visits foo.com/john**
By the looks, it uses the same index-file as if he would go to *foo.com*. Only difference is, that in the middle of the page it says **john**.

What I mean by this, is whatever directory is specified, the user still gets directed to the root-index, so the URL is sort of manupulated. And also the directory specified gets stored in a variable.

How would I be able to achieve this with JavaScript or JQuery? If possible then I'd rather do it in JQuery since that's what I'm using for the rest of my scripts on this project.

If anything seems unclear, don't hesitate to let me know and I'll do my best to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access [document.URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/URL) and [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) properties from Javascript. However, you should not rely on Javascript for handling that kind of redirections.

Best practice for handling these redirections mecanisms is to use web servers such as [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) and its [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module or [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/).
You can easily find [apache rewrite guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) or [nginx rewriting rules documentation](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) on internet.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the apache rules could simply be used in a htaccess?

Comment: Yes you can use rewrite rules within a .htaccess file with the mod_rewrite apache module. Be careful testing your rewrite rules on test/integration sites before applying them on a production site as you can easily break every incoming requests.

Comment: I see, thanks! Managed to do the rewrite where it is at a different URL but shows the root index. Currently testing the script to check directory!